# How to make Nautilus search useful outside of /home?

Tags: gnome3, search, nautilus

Nautilus search returns no results for anything outside of my home directory.  I've had this problem with both Ubuntu 10.10 Nautilus and the new Nautilus in Gnome 3.2.  I asked my friend using Fedora 15 if he had this limitation and he in fact did not.  I can use the "Search for Files" dialog to perform the searches, but not Nautilus.  What Gnome setting do I need to change?

Update:
It's slightly worse than I feared:  Nautilus seems to be employing only Tracker to perform searches and Tracker is being a couch potato. I ran `tracker-control -S` and it reported that all the miners were idle.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to try command line searching?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you navigate the nautilus to the parent directory of `/home`.

For example `File System` that you can search all of the file in your machine.

To perform search just simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Please note that: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome3 Classic.

Answer (score 1):

tracker is unfortunately quite convoluted; IIRC you can use tracker-settings to control which directories are (should be) indexed.

Comment: Yes, but tracker gets out of date quickly, which makes it less useful to me.  I'd rather have to endure a few seconds wait and have an accurate, up-to-date search.